# Grayed-out answers.

Tags: support, answers, user-interface

Could someone please explain why [this answer on the main site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2997116/show-that-2n-1-is-not-divisible-by-n-for-n1/2997118#2997118) appears grayed-out, but when I put my mouse over it, it springs into life like a regular answer. There are two other answers to that question and both appear like regular answers.

I don't think it's a deleted answer as I don't have sufficient rep points to see deleted stuff.

Comment: It's because the answer has a net score of $\leq -3$ (though it might happen at net scores of $\leq -2$; I'm not altogether sure when the "graying out" kicks in.).  When an answer is heavily downvoted, it "grays-out", unless you hover over it.  This is by design, to help deflect from a potentially problematic answer.

Comment: @amWhy: "*This is by design, to help deflect from a potentially problematic answer.*" For me, the first few times I encountered this the difference in background drew my attention **towards** the answer. However, I've seen enough of these now to recognize it's a signal for being down-voted a bit (how much, I never knew nor really cared).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed, an answer appears in gray text (unless hovering over it) when its net score is $\leq -3$.  Please see [this post on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44248/why-is-the-text-of-this-answer-gray) for confirmation.

Comment: Thankyou for the explanation. Does this appear in the Help Centre? I did have a look and didn't see anything. Maybe it should be added.